# Mongodb unable to connect to cluster

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

We are using mongodb community addition .
We are able to connect to independent nodes primary, and 2 replicas using direct connection.
But when we try to connect to replica set using url:-

```
mongodb://sorterapp:SorTErRwXpressXb@3.109.226.31:27017,15.207.33.131:27017,13.234.13.53:27017/?authSource=sorter&replicaSet=stagesorter
```

It is not able to connect.
Error:-
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND primary

Not sure what is the error
We tried using mongo compass as well as application library

Comment: Did you try with hostnames? Should be preferred over IP-Address anyway. Did you initiate the replica set?

Comment: we initiated the replica set and tried  hostnames also